# Windows 10 Taskbar JumpList Issue, Not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, shortcuts, jumplist

Issue: I'm having trouble with the Taskbar and Windows Explorer. I right-click on Notepad (that I've pinned to my "taskbar"), I try opening a previously pinned file (or recently used in the list that comes up when you right-click), and my pinned files no longer open (for ANY program pinned to my "Start" and/or "Taskbar"). I love having those shortcuts. So I tried to find the solution. I try right clicking on my pinned "File Explorer" folder to open lets say a 2nd window (to browse files), which I used to be able to do. Here's a screenshot of the visual and a blank box that pops up when trying to left click on a pinned file from the taskbar:

[image: Screen Shot]

Steps: I've recently reinstalled Windows 10 Pro from scratch (meaning a fresh download from their website, not a backup image). I was able to access pinned documents for the first day or first so many hours. But after installing updates from Windows 10, I eventually lost the ability to open said windows.

I can use Windows Key + E to open another window (but that's not really the point as I have "Quick Access" locations also pinned, and I like to open them from the taskbar. I can successfully right-click the Quick Access locations from an already opened Windows Explorer Window, but the main issue is my notepad, and all other programs now no longer allow me to right-click to open another instance. I have a laptop that I use everyday as well, and these issues aren't present on my laptop, only on my desktop. I've setup a Virtual Machine, and it works and continues to work in that environment, so I'm not sure what to do.

Main Question: I'm comfortable altering the registry enough to add keys, or registry items, or check mine with another computer if someone knows the location that this issue resides within the registry. I'd be willing to spend a few hours comparing my desktop registry with my laptop if someone can point me to the locations. I don't want to call Microsoft ... yet. Please help me learn how to fix this.

Comment: I have the same problem and have tried many solutions (superuser.com/questions/1321248/broken-jump-lists-on-windows-10). Maybe some of the things I listed could help you resolve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to use “sfc /scannow” to check/repair system files.

Also, please try to add a new administrator account, switch to use the new user account to log on system, confirm that if it is working with new user profile.

Besides, as you had mentioned that, problem happens after installing Windows Update, if possible, you may try to un-install these updates, re-start the system and check the result.

Please back up system and important data before any changing. It would be helpful for restoration if there is any problem happens after the change.

Best Regards,
Eve Wang

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention I ran "sfc /scannow" about 6 times ... I doubled the recommended amount just to be sure. It didn't fix it. That includes restarting my computer between each run.

But I will definitely try creating an new user account, and see if that account has issues or not. Thank you for you comments Eve. All suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: I just tried the adding a user account, and it works there. So is there a way to export a portion of the registry to my main user account that has this issue? Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, it would be difficult to identify the detail registry which causing the problem. A possible way would be export registry configuration of both accounts, and compare them to find the difference.  In general, if new user account is working, a simple method would be migrate user data from original one to this new one. And give this new account the appropriate permission to replace the problematic user account.