# Broken jump lists on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, start-menu, jumplist

I have noticed that all my taskbar and start menu jump lists are broken. They are broken in a very specific way:

- The items show up, but clicking them does nothing (clicking dismisses the jump list, but does not open the corresponding app)
- None of the items show a context menu when right-clicked (an empty gray box appears, as if an empty context menu appeared)
- Jump lists and the context menus work in safe mode

My problem is very similar (if not identical) to the one described in [Windows 10 Taskbar JumpList Issue, Not working](https://superuser.com/questions/1252550/windows-10-taskbar-jumplist-issue-not-working) and in [Taskbar > File Explorer > Context Menu failing me](https://superuser.com/questions/1278790/taskbar-file-explorer-context-menu-failing-me) and in the related [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/8ecy33/windows_10_1709_jump_lists_not_working/) and in the [related forum post](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/74057-windows-10-blank-context-menu-pinned-items-taskbar.html). However, I have more information on the potential cause and more attempted solutions.

There are also two related posts on Microsoft Answers: [related post on Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/jump-lists-not-working-in-windows-10/f03cd014-6784-4d81-8735-3beb9877db5a?page=2) and [the other related post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-winpc/windows-10-jump-list-on-taskbar-when-click-on-to/d82cfc59-a5d4-484c-b182-564be2fbe8e2), but none of the solutions worked for me (or for the original posters).

I noticed this in Anniversary Update, after updating Visual Studio. Then, I updated to April Update, which fixed the issue. Now, I updated Visual Studio (from 15.6 to 15.7) and it is broken again. The jump lists are broken on both the taskbar and start menu, and they are broken for all apps (both desktop and store).

Things I tried:

- Deleting all files from the `AutomaticDestinations` directory
- Deleting some files from the `AutomaticDestinations` directory
- Resetting jump lists from settings
- Reinstalling all Store apps with a PowerShell script
- Running `sfc /scannow`
- Running `dism` with restore health option
- Pinning items
- Restarting the computer
- Restarting in safe mode and then restarting again
- Disabling Internet Explorer
- Using the Start Menu troubleshooter: It finds corruptions, but does not apply a fix
- Copying `TileDataLayer` folder from different computers and then repairing
- Creating a new user account (this also does not work)
- Repairing Visual Studio (it just made Visual Studio slower)
- Restoring the original `AppData` folder location and creating a junction point to it from the other partition
- Removing all junction points related to Visual Studio
- Completely removing all versions of Visual Studio and fresh installing Visual Studio 2017
- Installing April Update
- Installing October Update
- Using the `ShellExView` to disable all shell extensions with `Context Menu` flag and all shell extensions whose `File Created` time and `CLSID Modified Time` was after the problems started occurring
- Running the recommended script `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}` which helps fix similar problems
- Posting an issue on the Visual Studio feedback site and through the Feedback Hub application and waiting for a fix
- Removing all CD/DVD mounting software
- Turning jump lists on and off in the Settings
- Setting the `JumpListItems_Maximum` in the registry
- Using `msconfig` to test different startup configurations (disabling all non-Microsoft services – jump lists do not work, diagnostic startup – jump lists do not work; safe-mode – jump lists work)
- Disabling OneDrive (both in startup and from Group Policy) – interestingly, the items that are opened from OneDrive do work; but all other items do not (both clicking and the context-menu).
- Removing all Anti-Virus software

I have some junction points on my C: drive (all in `Program Files` and `ProgramData`).

It also seems that Cortana shortcut button (<kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) gets broken whenever jump lists are broken (which is usually within a few days after repair installing Windows 10).

Can anyone provide any clues or suggestions?

### Edit 1 (After restoring the default `AppData` folder)

A peculiar thing happens when accessing the `Recent Items` folder: when accessed by navigating directly to it in explorer, it does not contain the `CustomDestinations` and `AutomaticDestinations` folders, but when accessed by entering the same directory into Run the folders are visible along with many items that do not appear in jump lists.

### Edit 2 (After repairing Windows installation)

Even though reupdating system to April Update resolved the problem, the question remains, since the actual cause of the problem is unidentified and I expect it to happen again after another Visual Studio update.

### Edit 3 (After a few days)

After about two days of working properly after doing the repair install, my jump lists are not working again. All the history items are shown, but they are again unclickable and the context-menus are empty. Obviously, doing a repair install every few days is not an option. During the few days that the jump lists worked properly, I did not install anything on my system.

### Edit 4 (After removing Visual Studio and removing junction points)

After opening Visual Studio 2017 and running a UWP (Microsoft Store) app with a debugger attached, my jump lists were destroyed again.

I decided to remove both Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017 and reinstall Visual Studio 2017, remove all junction points I had (I had some junction points for Visual Studio installation), reinstall Visual Studio 2017 and repair install Windows. Removing Visual Studio installations and the junction points did not fix the issue. Repair installing did, as noted in the answer. However, setting up a scheduled task to reinstall Windows ever few days is really not a solution.

### Edit 5 (After updating Visual Studio to 15.7.3)

The jump lists are broken again. They have been working for almost a few weeks. After Visual Studio update the jump lists show the same broken behavior.

### Edit 6 (After updating Windows 10 to October 2018 Update)

Fixed for five days and then broken again. Possibly related to Visual Studio again. They seem to break when a UWP application is deployed.

### Edit 7 (After meddling with startup configuration)

After trying to disable shell extensions, startup items and services, by various means (including `msconfig`, `ShellExView`, the Task Manager, the Registry Editor and the Services application), I have concluded that the only state in which the Jump Lists work is safe mode.

### Edit 8 (After the insightful answer by Zenithies)

I have realized that I have many 10000, 10001 and 10016 errors in the Event Log. The 10000 and 10001 errors occur after attempting to click on a jump list item. Below are the errors.

> Unable to start a DCOM Server: {C82192EE-6CB5-4BC0-9EF0-FB818773790A}.
>
> Unable to start a DCOM Server: {9AA46009-3CE0-458A-A354-715610A075E6} as Unavailable/Unavailable.
>
> The application-specific permission
>    settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID {2593F8B9-4EAF-457C-B68A-50F6B8EA6B54} and APPID {15C20B67-12E7-4BB6-92BB-7AFF07997402}

After going through the registry, I identified one of these to be the RuntimeBroker component. I proceeded to see the corresponding component service and noticed I had duplicate entries for `rundll32.exe` and `RuntimeBroker` components similar to the [Runtime DCOM Server appears twice](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/runtimebroker-dcom-server-appears-twice/d0cf17a2-6a9c-4d0f-ba04-cc392e939053) post. When trying to modify permissions I get the following error.

> One or more of the permission entries attached to Registry Value has an unrecognized type and can not be displayed.

The jump list issues can be circumvented by manually calling the jump list component. However, the permission issue still exists and the cause is probably one of the Windows updates, considering that the Runtime Broker component service is duplicated and has a different ID.

The related post has more info on this: [Unable to start a DCOM Server](https://superuser.com/questions/1443407/unable-to-start-a-dcom-server).

### Edit 9 (After updating Windows to 1903 and Visual Studio to 2019)

As with updates before, the lists were fixed for a couple of days.

The lists are now broken again, but now a menu is shown with the text "This item is unavailable" and prompts to delete it from the list. After running the temporary fix script from Edit 8, the problem is resolved until the next shutdown. I've reported this through Feedback Hub, once again.

### Edit 10 (After updating Windows to 2004)

Still broken. Every major Windows update seems to disable the Task Scheduler fix. Re-enabling the scheduled script fixes the problem. However, the cause of the problem is not resolved. This is still only circumventing the problem.

Comment: You will need to remove Visual Studio and reinstall it in order to fix this problem.  Worth pointing out this honestly sounds like an issue with your configuration, specifically, the junction points you have configured.

Comment: @Ramhound Are you sure this is a solution? Do you know, from experience, that it is indeed the issue? I really don't want to reinstall Visual Studio if I don't have to.

Comment: If I was not fairly confident, about the reason this problem even happens, I wouldn't have suggested it that solution.  However, I don't believe in submitting single sentences as an answer, to any question especially to a problem that is as nuanced as this one.

Comment: Repairing did not work.

Comment: Can you try to undo the junction point on `AppData/Roaming` ? And which ones have you created in Program Files?

Comment: Junction points are just user software. I didn't touch the `Common Files` or anything similar. The `Roaming` folder location was changed in the registry. I will try to put this back, but that might be a problem, since some apps remember the location of the roaming folder.

Comment: I restored original settings for `AppData`. Still does not work. I don't think it is an issue with that. The right-click menus are not showing properly.

Comment: My suspicion is that this is somehow connected with the junction points, as some Windows folders are rather sensitive. You might need to go as far as doing [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) to reestablish them. If going this way, take first good backups including an image of the system disk, but not using the problematic Windows Backup. I recommend the free [AOMEI Backupper Standard](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html).

Comment: I thought that too, but really wanted to avoid it. I have a custom setup with multiple SSDs and HDDs and junction points from C: to D: for user software. Backing up is not really an option, since it would take too long. I'm going to try it anyway.

Comment: @Ramhound Reinstalling Visual Studio did not help. Repairing the system did not help.

Answer (score 4):

Another workaround worth trying:

#### Checking the possible cause of trouble:

- Click random jump list item that does not work a few times.
- Run `Event Viewer` (ie: <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> `-> eventvwr.msc`)
- Check section `Windows Logs -> System`
- If you can see bunch of errors with `DistributedCOM` source and ID `10000` and error message that reads as: `Unable to start a DCOM Server: {C82192EE-6CB5-4BC0-9EF0-FB818773790A}`, please continue:

#### Running JumpViewerExecuteHelper manually

- <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- run: `%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,SHCreateLocalServerRunDll {c82192ee-6cb5-4bc0-9ef0-fb818773790a}`
- If this is root cause of your trouble, UAC will ask you for elevated permissions for *rundll32.exe* process
- After confirm, your jump lists should be working. (until restart or logging-off)

If this is the case, you can now create a shortcut:

#### Adding startup shortcut

- `desktop` <kbd>Right Click</kbd>`->`<kbd>New</kbd>`->`<kbd>Shortcut</kbd>
- target: `%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,SHCreateLocalServerRunDll {c82192ee-6cb5-4bc0-9ef0-fb818773790a}`, named `JumpListFix` or anything of your liking
- copy shortcut into `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` location, so you don't have to run it manually after each boot.

#### Notes

- I have same problem on two different machines with Win 10 Home and Pro, both October 2018, Home is fresh-install
- When I tried: <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> `-> dcomcnfg.exe` to check permissions on, I've got warning: `The CLSID {c82192ee-6cb5-4bc0-9ef0-fb818773790a}, item C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe and title JumpViewerExecuteHelper has named value AppID, but is not recorded under \\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Appid. Do you wish to record it?`
- Adding it have not fixed the problem, fiddling with JumpViewerExecuteHelper permissions with dcomcnfg.exe didn't any good either.

Comment: In my case, I have duplicate entries for the RuntimeBroker in component services. Thank you very much. You've been extremely helpful. I think this problem is still not resolved, as I still cannot fix it at the root. I can only circumvent it temporarily.

Comment: I had the same issue and this solution worked for me.

Comment: This also fixes a similar issue where jump lists stop updating.

Answer (score 3):

**Here is what finally worked for me:**

• Run `Task Scheduler` (<kbd>Winkey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → `taskschd.msc`)

• Click `Action` and select `Create Basic Task...`

• Enter a name and click `Next`

• Select the `When I log on` , click `Next`

• Select `Start a program`, click `Next`

• Paste the following script `%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,SHCreateLocalServerRunDll {c82192ee-6cb5-4bc0-9ef0-fb818773790a}`
Click `Next` and select `Yes` on the pop-up window, then `Finish`

Restart your computer and hopefully you'll have your problem fixed!

Edit: In case this does not work, try to edit the trigger to `Delay task for 1 minute` by right clicking the task you created, then selecting `Properties` then `Triggers` and `Edit...`

Comment: As I described in my answer (based on Zenithies' answer), this does work. However, this is not an actual solution, but merely a workaround. What is causing the problem initially? I would like to fix the problem rather than treat a symptom. Cortana is broken along with the jump lists. Something else could possibly be broken with a similar cause. I suspect that the cause is Visual Studio app deployment process, but that needs more investigation.

Comment: @IgorŠevo I am not sure what is causing the problem initially, however I've never installed Visual Studio in the device with the broken jump lists.

Comment: Wow. That's helpful, but now I'm back to no hypotheses. :)

Answer (score 0):

I used the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to create a Windows 10 ISO file. I then ran an installation of April Update (even though I had April Update installed) to "upgrade" my computer. The installation finished and the problem is now resolved. However, this is not a real solution, considering that it is quite bothersome to have to reinstall Windows every time I update Visual Studio 2017.

I had submitted feedback through the Feedback Hub and a Microsoft engineer replied that the issue was fixed in build 17682. I have yet to confirm this.

### Edit (October 2018)

I can confirm that the issue is not fixed in build 17763.1. I have submitted another report through Feedback Hub.

### Edit (December 2018)

I have applied a fix from Zenithies's answer. However, this only circumvents the actual problem described in the last edit.

### Edit (June 2019, Windows 1903)

I created a scheduled task to run both failing processes (both Cortana and Jump Lists) at log on. I set it to be delayed by 5 seconds. Also, I'm running it with administrator privileges. This resolves the problem partially (I can now use the jump lists). However, the errors are still listed in the Event Viewer. This means that the problem is still unresolved, only circumvented.

I also submitted multiple reports through Feedback Hub, including a link to this post and the related post ([Unable to start a DCOM Server](https://superuser.com/questions/1443407/unable-to-start-a-dcom-server)).

Comment: I'm happy to know that my suggestion in the comment worked for you, but the normal practice is to invite the commenter to write the answer, and especially when a bounty is involved.

Comment: I don't consider this an actual solution and don't really mean to accept my own answer. It did work, but it seems like an unnecessary effort for something seemingly simple. If by the day before the end of bounty period there is no other reasonable answer, you can write your suggestion as an answer and I will remove this one.

Comment: For a real "solution" one would need to know exactly what changes you have done to Windows that caused the problem, otherwise the only solution is the big hammer. In general, Windows has a very complex structure, too complex even for Microsoft to fully control. Even experts hesitate to make any changes, especially untested ones, since small changes may have unforeseen large effects. But I think that you have found that out by now ;)

Comment: I'm fairly convinced that the installation of Visual Studio is what broke it, but I guess I'll have to wait for the next update. In any case, post your answer and if there isn't a better answer, the bounty points are yours.

Comment: I've got several versions of Visual Studio installed side-by-side and I update them regularly, with no problems with jump-lists, but my Windows setup is fairly standard with no added junctions. It's possible that the installation in your case was confused by these changes - Windows doesn't always handle junctions correctly.

Comment: Try deploying a UWP app locally and debugging it. I'm not entirely sure, but it might be what breaks the jump lists.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot know exactly what changes were done to your Windows setup,
so cannot analyze their effects. Some Windows products don't work well
with sensitive folders replaced by junctions, and the installation
of Visual Studio is extremely massive, making lots of additions
and changes to the Windows system.

In such difficult cases to analyze,
the solution might be to use a big hammer - Repair Install.
This does an in-place upgrade without losing anything other than all installed Windows Updates. It requires the installed Windows to be able to boot
and to run the installation process. It is also very important to use
the Windows installation media of the same major version of Windows
as is installed. Run Windows Update afterward, as all updates will be lost.

There is no guarantee that this will fix all the problems,
since this is not a clean install. Many settings that you changed will
stay, so this is not a cure-all solution.
But it is better than the destructive
[Reset](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4130-reset-windows-10-a.html)
or
[Refresh](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4090-refresh-windows-10-a.html).

For directions on performing the Repair Install see the article
[How to Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: It seems that the jump lists have a tendency to self-destruct. After a few days of normal work, they are broken again.

Comment: Your setup is self-destructing. I hate to say, but it seems to me impossible to analyze the problem in a non-standard setup such as yours, especially since it doesn't happen elsewhere. I hate to say it, but since this big gun didn't do the job, a bigger one is required. My above link also refers to the Reset and Refresh options, where Reset may optionally at least keep your personal files. Before starting, take good backups including disk image (AOMEI recommended) and test the restoration CD/USB. Next time I suggest avoiding structural changes in Windows - other easy solutions exist, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue with Excel for the last few months; that app seems to be the worst offender. In desperation, I cleared it thusly a while ago:
In Settings>Personalization>Start, find "Show recently opened items in Jump Lists on Start or the taskbar and File explorer Quick Access. If it's turned on, turn it off briefly - which will clear all but pinned items from all jump lists - then on again. The Excel jump list started loading again; I'll watch it for at least 2 more sessions to make sure it's resolved.

Comment: I'm aware of this circumvent, but this isn't my issue. In my case, all jump lists are broken (so, no jump lists for any of the apps).

Answer (score 0):

Unpin the program icon from the task bar. Disable jump lists. Re-pin the program to the task bar and enable jump lists.

Problem appears to be resolved.