# Unable to start a DCOM Server

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, taskbar, dcom

Windows jump lists and Cortana <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> command are not working. The jump list issue is also documented in the [Broken jump lists on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1321248/broken-jump-lists-on-windows-10).

Searching through the Event Viewer, I found two errors.

For Jump lists (Event ID 10000):

> Unable to start a DCOM Server: {C82192EE-6CB5-4BC0-9EF0-FB818773790A}.
> The error: "2147943140" Happened while starting this command:
>
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,SHCreateLocalServerRunDll
> {c82192ee-6cb5-4bc0-9ef0-fb818773790a} -Embedding

For Cortana (Event ID 10001):

> Unable to start a DCOM Server: {24AC8F2B-4D4A-4C17-9607-6A4B14068F97}
> as Unavailable/Unavailable. The error: "2147943140" Happened while
> starting this command:
>
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe
> shell32.dll,SHCreateLocalServerRunDll
> {24AC8F2B-4D4A-4C17-9607-6A4B14068F97} -Embedding

Manually running the commands fixes the issue until the next reboot. However, even when using a scheduled task, the commands cannot be run and fail with, presumably, the same error.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

The only thing, of [many that I've tried](https://superuser.com/questions/1321248/broken-jump-lists-on-windows-10), that works (temporarily) is to do a Repair install of Windows or to update to a new version (I am currently running 1903). This works for a few days, and then gets broken again. I suspect that deploying a Microsoft Store app from Visual Studio is what breaks it, but I am not entirely sure.

From what I've read elsewhere, this might be some kind of a permissions problem.

I also get a warning on Event ID 10016:

> The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation
> permission for the COM Server application with CLSID
> {C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239}  and APPID
> {316CDED5-E4AE-4B15-9113-7055D84DCC97}  to the user *[---]* from address
> LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container
> Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.18362.145_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
> SID *[---]*.
> This security permission can be modified using the Component Services
> administrative tool.

I tried using the Component Services tool, but could not find anything with the given ID.