# Google Chrome jump list tasks aren't working

Tags: google-chrome, jumplist

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>The item you selected is unavailable. It might have been moved, renamed, or removed.</sub>
<sup>Do you want to remove it from the list?</sup>

If you use StartIsBack, you get this error message:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
The specified path does not exist.

Check the path, and then try again.
```

I installed the 64-bit version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was searching for a solution to this very problem, and I was able to solve it.

1. Using Juggler's advice, I turned on the "Show recently opened items in Jump Lists" in the Start settings.
2. Then I waited a few minutes for the list to visually update on the taskbar. When the recent items showed up, the shortcuts for new window and new incognito window started working again.

It appears the problem is that Windows doesn't update the jump list after a new reinstall, since Google Chrome now installs in the Program Files folder rather than the (x86) folder. Turning on recent items in the settings forces Windows to recheck the shortcuts, which fixes the problem. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Same here. I've tried the following, but I couldn't get the jump list tasks to work:

1. Reinstalled Chrome
2. Reinstalled Chrome after clearing relevant files/folders
3. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/the-item-you-selected-is-unavailable-it-may-have/324439f4-b112-4dc7-a06f-449713bce028
4. One of the fixes mentioned here which is just like #3 - [Broken jump lists on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1321248/broken-jump-lists-on-windows-10)

**UPDATE**

**I made it work again by simply playing around with the Settings>Start.** This Youtube video should give you an idea
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WG1tv-kceF4

Here's what I did:

1. Disabled recent items in the jump lists
2. Opened some websites in Chrome (both in regular and incognito tabs)
3. Closed Chrome
4. Enabled recent items in the jump lists
5. Did #2 again and tried checking the jump list, didn't change so I thought it didn't work
6. I just browsed some more websites cause I gave up on this (heh)
7. Checked it again a few minutes later hoping something changes and yeah, somehow got it fixed, the tasks (**New window** and **New Incognito window**) appeared again with the recent items above them

Comment: Opening some websites in Chrome (**both** in regular and incognito tabs) did the trick.

Answer (score -2):

Run command prompt and paste this `cmd.exe /c del "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms"`

https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-quick-access-reset-pinned-shortcuts-stuck-not-working-windows-10/