# Windows 10 store applications like Calc, Snipping Tool, etc. are acting slow

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, microsoft-store

With my Windows 10 machine, I am experiencing the following strange behavior:

Almost every application with a UI sourced from the Microsoft Store is acting slow, for example the calculator. When I turn it on, it appears immediately, but when I click it, it takes more than 30 seconds before I can input numbers. The same goes for the Snipping tool. When I take a screenshot and open it, it takes about 30 seconds before I can do anything with it.

Interestingly, after a while, some of the apps cause the explorer.exe to crash. Once it crashes and auto-reloads, the issues are gone until the next boot.

So far, I've tried all the standard system health and integrity checks, but everything comes back clean.

When the explorer.exe crashes, it is noted in the Event Log as an "Application Hang" event 1002.

**Update 1**

By narrowing down possible culprits, I figured out that it has something to do with pasting images into the WhatsApp Windows application. If the WhatsApp application is not launched at startup, the problem won't manifest immediately. However, once I launch it, everything works fine until I paste a screenshot into a WhatsApp window. Then, delays start to appear, and it seems like the Windows taskbar is affected too. Still, everything miraculously gets cured by an explorer.exe crash.

**Update 2**

It looks like, the issue is related to the fix of [Broken jump lists on windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1321248/broken-jump-lists-on-windows-10/). When I disabled workaround for broken jump lists, system started to behave correctly. I will keep my eye on it for a while.

Comment: Does this behavior happen while in Safe Mode.  Instead of submitting a commnet you should [edit] your question.  Your question is very light on information to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @Ramhound It does not do it in safe mode

Comment: @harrymc As I stated in original post, I tried all standard system health / integrity checks already and it didn't help.

Comment: Try to disable your security software and test. If it still happens, run deep anti-virus scans by your antivirus and [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).

Comment: @Zenithies - So it does NOT happen while in Safe Mode.  The next step is to disable everything that is automatically ran with AutoRuns, and semantically enable each entry, until you identify the entry that causes the behavior.